# Should I unsubscribe from pipe() in Angular?

Tags: angular, rest, observable

I've read some articles about Observable and unsubscribes. But I don't understand a bit of information about the pipe(). Pipe automatically unsubscribes in some cases. What are these cases? I have one service for connecting to my server and one component. Should I unsubscribe here and using ngOnDestroy? It simple service for CRUD application.

For example, one method from service:

```js
public getSubject(size:number, page:number) : Observable<Subject[]> {
  return this.http.get<Subject[]>(environment.apiUrl + '/subject?size='+size+'&page='+page)
    .pipe(
      map(data=>{
        return  data;
      }),
      catchError(err => {
        return throwError(err);
      }));
}
```

And component using the service with destroyer.

```js
    //...some code
pageClick() {
  this.subscriptions.add(this.connector.getSubject(this.pageSize, this.page - 1)
    .subscribe(data => {                                                                        
      this.subject = data;                                                                                  
      this.errorFlag = false;

    }, error => {                                                             
      this.error = error.error.message;                                                                                          
      this.errorFlag = true;

    }));
}
    //..some code..

@HostListener('window:beforeunload')
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.subscriptions.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: `httpClient` unsubscribes itself. Also any operator that completes the stream unsubscribes it. But that has nothing to do with `pipe` and all to do with which operator we're using. `take(number)` for examples unsubscribes.

Comment: @ritaj, that's not how it works. http client has no knowledge about subscriptions. it only returns observable

Comment: Which completes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no need to unsubscribe completed Observable. When HttpClient gets response from server and emits it to subscription in component Observable is completed, so it emits no more values. If it's not emitting values, there is no risk of memory leak, which is reason unsubscribing.

"Pipe automatically unsubscribes in some cases" - **.pipe** is used to modify stream of data by adding some operators to it. It is not responsible for subscribing nor unsubscribing.